# PHP Line feed not generating line feed

Tags: php

First of all I apologize for asking such a basic question. I tried to search online but the code for line feed is not working for me, maybe you can help. I am trying to display two POST variable on separate lines, but it is not happening:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['customer'];
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo $_POST['submit'];
?>
<html>
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="customer" type="text" value="hey" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="WantSubmit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

The output is:
hey WantSubmit

Comment: Try `echo $_POST['customer'] . "<br>" . $_POST['submit'];` or replace your `\n` by `<br>`

Comment: Take a look at the html source the browser sees (Ctrl+U, or some "view source" menu entry) and then think for a moment ;-)

Comment: Wrap with the pre tag too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the source code of the page, you will see the new lines.

The problem is that your page is being rendered with HTML, and you are not using HTML new lines. Try:

```
echo "<br />\n";
```

instead.

Alternatively, you could ask your browser to render the page as plain text by adding:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

(but then the HTML will not work).

Comment: `echo "<br />n";` will echo `n` with a blank space on top of `n`

Comment: Correct you are. Fixed :)